# can not enter addEventListener on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-cloud-firestore, materialize

**db-kepala-ruangan.js**

```
 var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
      var dragon = document.createElement("label");
      dragon.innerHTML = "imam";
      for(var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++){
            checkbox[i].addEventListener("change", checkedOrNot)
          }

          function checkedOrNot() {
            var isChecked = this.checked;

            if (isChecked) { //checked
              console.log('checked');
            } else { //unchecked
              console.log('unchecked');
            }
          }
```

i'm using materialize & cloud firestore for this stuff.

this is the complete project https://github.com/imamdtechnolife/simpelkes

Comment: For my understanding: you want add addlistener for checkbox?

Comment: @imam please check answer below.

Comment: @PraveenGopal yes i think so..

Comment: @SwaroopDeval I have already applied the solution that you gave Brother,, but still not working,

Comment: @ImamAfriyadiwhat is the issue? The code in my answer working fine. Please confirm the code you modified and if there is any error on console.

Comment: The code inside your question doesn't use Firestore or Materialize. If those technologies are relevant to the help you're asking for, make sure that your question includes the information we need about that. A link to an external project is not enough, you must include the necessary information in your question itself. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okey, thank you mr. . i'm sorry for that.

Comment: i try to improve my question ^^

Answer (score 0):

To add event listener to all checkboxes, you have to fetch all tags with name `input` and add event listener to only those whose type is `checkbox`.

```js
var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++){
    if(inputList[i].type == "checkbox") {
        inputList[i].addEventListener("change", checkedOrNot)
    }
}

function checkedOrNot() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;

    if (isChecked) { //checked
        console.log('checked');
    } else { //unchecked
        console.log('unchecked');
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


  <form action="#">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Red</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        <span>Yellow</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
        <span>Filled in</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input id="indeterminate-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <span>Indeterminate Style</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
        <span>Green</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
        <span>Brown</span>
      </label>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you give exemple using materialize brother, because i'm using materiaze for this project

Comment: It has nothing to do with frontend framwork you use.

Comment: @ImamAfriyadi added materialize as well.

Comment: this is brother, <https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uDkgp2vaVadYaXeK7q6CO5HELtiV9-l->

log "checked" or "unchecked" not to show.

i'm using these codes for my project:
<https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imamdtechnolife/simpelkes/simpalkes_v1.0/public/js/ui-kepala-ruangan.js>

Comment: make drive link sharable please

Comment: @ImamAfriyadi the code you shared doesn't have the code you mentioned in the question. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imamdtechnolife/simpelkes/simpalkes_v1.0/public/js/ui-kepala-ruangan.js

Comment: this is brother

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12ULJmEAmvjor5jnLXafeiCKEg8zMYwSZ

Comment: can you please tell me the value of checkbox.length?